# Button Alignment to Center?

Tags: html

I have a button and i want to align it to the center of a page ? how to do that ?

```
<button type="button" style="text-align: center" class="btn btn-info">
   Discover More
</button>
```

I shall be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your button into a div with centred text.
Here is an example:

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
   Discover More
  </button>
</div>
```